# Indefinite stale of TCP packet reception

Tags: java, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

**Deplyment environment:**
I have created a TCP server using JAVA over windows 10 OS. My TCP client program is written in VC++ and runs on windows 7 OS (I don't have any control over this part of the code, it is a black box to me).

**My TCP server code is like this:**

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
s.setReceiveBufferSize(2000);
s.setSendBufferSize(2000);
s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
s.setKeepAlive(true);
new TcpConnectionHandler(s,this.packetHandler);
```

**Following is the TCP connection handler snippet:**

```
InputStream incomingPacketBuffer = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream outgoingPacketBuffer = this.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
int bufferLen=0;
byte inBuffer[] = new byte[this.clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
byte outBuffer[] = new byte[this.clientSocket.getSendBufferSize()]; 
while(this.clientSocket.isConnected())
{
    bufferLen = incomingPacketBuffer.read(inBuffer);
    if(bufferLen>0)
    {
        outBuffer = (byte[]) this.packetHandlerModule.invoke(this.packetHandler,Arrays.copyOf(inBuffer, bufferLen));
    }
    if(outBuffer != null)
    {
        if(this.clientSocket.isConnected())
        {
            outgoingPacketBuffer.write(outBuffer);
            outgoingPacketBuffer.flush();
        }
    }
}
this.clientSocket.close();
```

The communication is packet based and the protocol/parsing is handled by `packetHandler`.

**Two more variant I've tried:**

1. I have tried to close the socket as and when a reply is sent back to the client. That is, after receiving one packet of data, I reply to the client and close the connection.
2. I used `inputStream.available` before using the `read` method.

**The problem I face:**

Most of the time the TCP server replies to incoming packets within a second. If the server receives a packet after some idle time, the server doesn't reply to the packet. Sometimes even when there is active communication is going on, the reply is not being transmitted. Secondly, the `isConnected` function returns true even when the client socket closed the connection.

**Debugging attempts:**

1. I used teraterm to send packets and checked it. The behavior is same. As long as I send packets one after another, I don't have an issue. If one packet doesn't get a reply, then every packet sent after that does not get reply from the server.
2. When I press Ctrl+C in server console, all the packets sent from teraterm is processed by TCP server and reply is sent back. After this the server works properly for some duration.
3. I checked the packet flow with wireshark. When the replies are sent back normally, it is sent along with the ACK of client request (SYN, SYN+ACK, ACK, PSH, PSH+ACK, FYN, FYN+ACK, ACK). When the reply gets staled (may not be the right term, it is stuck in inputStream.available or inputStream.read), only ACK packet is sent by server (SYN, SYN+ACK, ACK, PSH, ACK).
4. I checked many forums and other threads in stackexchange, learned about Nagle's algorithm, applicaion must take care of packetization in TCP, TCP may receive 10+10 packets as 8+12 or 15+5 or any such manner. The server code takes care of packetization, `setKeepAlive` is set to true (there is no problem when a packet is sent from server).

Problem in short: "At times, TCP read call is getting blocked for a long duration even when there is incoming packets. When Ctrl+C is pressed, they are getting processed."

PS: I just started posting queries on stackexchange, so kindly let me know if there is any issues in the way of formulating the query.

PPS: Sorry for such a long post.

**UPDATE**

1. The comment from *EJB* helped me to identify the peer disconnect.
2. I made another setup with Ubuntu 16.04 as operating system for server. It has been 3 days, windows system had the issue occasionally. Ubuntu 16.04 never staled.

Comment: `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the points you are testing it. It isn't a test for peer disconnection, but `read()` returning -1 is, and you are ignoring that.

Comment: @EJB, thanks. This helped me in closing the connection properly.

Comment: I'm sure it helped you but it isn't reflected in the code in your question. What does 'indefinite stale' mean?

Comment: The client sent a packet to server. Wireshark at server shows an ack being sent back to the client. But no reply has been sent. In debug mode I understood that the read call never returned. If I press Ctrl+C in command prompt, then the read returns and packet is being processed. I ran another instance of server over Ubuntu 16.04, till now I have not faced any issue. My requirement is that it should run in Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider;

- the TCP buffer sizes are usually 8K at least and I don't think you can skink them to 2000 bytes, or if you can, I don't think it's a good idea.
- the size of the `byte[]` doesn't really matter over about 2K, you may as well pick a value.
- you can't need to be creating a buffer more than once.

So in short I would try.

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
s.setKeepAlive(true);
new TcpConnectionHandler(s,this.packetHandler);
```

and

```
try {
    InputStream in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = this.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    int bufferLen = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    while ((bufferLen = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bufferLen); // not buffered so no need to flush
    }
} finally {
    this.clientSocket.close();
}
```

> At times, TCP read call is getting blocked for a long duration even when there is incoming packets.

Would write a test Java client to see that this is not due to behaviour in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I understand that creation of buffer every time is not required. But the main problem still remains. The maximum size of my packet is limited to 200 bytes, so 2k sufficient to handle as of now. As I mentioned already, I used the teraterm to connect to my server using TCP protocol. There also, at random time I get this block.

I think the key here is Ctrl+C in terminal. When I interrupt the terminal the packets are getting served.

Comment: @Raavanan the code above should do what you want in which case I would write a java client to prove this. I don't know if your terminal program does anything unusual.

Comment: The problem is not with the terminal, I have used the terminal to check other cases. Anyways, the operating system also makes some difference I suppose. Please see the update.